# SHILCreateFromPath substitution in Win7?

Tags: winapi, windows-7

The `shell.SHILCreateFromPath` function creates a pointer to an item identifier list (PIDL) from a path.

As noted in the [MSDN Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the function is deprecated and the support ends with Windows XP.

What is the substitution in Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`SHParseDisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.